# How to add four spaces selected region

Tags: indentation, markdown-mode

I'm using Firefox extention `It's all text`, with it I can edit stackoverflow form text in Emacs.

Therefore I often want to add four spaces before selected text to markdown codes.
`indent-region` only "indent" the region. Is there already function like this or should I write it myself?

I already installed `markdown-mode`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `indent-rigidly` (C-x TAB or C-x C-i, see footnote) can help you.

> indent-rigidly is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `indent.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x TAB.
>
> (indent-rigidly START END ARG &optional INTERACTIVE)
>
> Indent all lines starting in the region. If called interactively with
>   no prefix argument, activate a transient mode in which the indentation
>   can be adjusted interactively by typing left, right, S-left, or
>   S-right. Typing any other key deactivates the transient mode.
>
> If called from a program, or interactively with prefix ARG, indent all
>   lines starting in the region forward by ARG columns. If called from a
>   program, START and END specify the beginning and end of the text to
>   act on, in place of the region.
>
> Negative values of ARG indent backward, so you can remove all
>   indentation by specifying a large negative ARG.

Footnote: C-x TAB is equivalent to C-x C-i. This was noted by nanny in the comment, and I think it's worth mentioning because C-x C-i is so much easier to hit.

Comment: Thanks! But my code `(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "TAB") '(lambda () (interactive) (indent-rigidly 4)))` fails with error `Wrong number of arguments: (3 . 4), 1` Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: the function takes 3 mandatory arguments, you gave it one. START and END would be the beginning and end of the region.

Comment: I use this function all the time to do exactly what OP is asking. I use the keystrokes: `C-u C-x C-i` to call it after marking a region (since `C-i` is the same as `TAB` and `C-u` gives it a numerical argument of 4).

Comment: (sorry, duplicate) As for the doc, this function requires 3 mandatory arguments. You gave it one. START and END would be the beginning and end of the region. See my answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks! I could do with `(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "TAB") '(lambda () (interactive)
                                             (indent-rigidly (region-beginning) (region-end) 4)))`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `rectangle-mark-mode`, down N lines, forward 4 spaces, then `open-rectangle`.

Comment: When I type spaces 4 times, the last line is already with spaces, and then `open-rectangle` make it 8 times spaces. Other lines works fine, though.

Comment: I don't think he meant to insert 4 space but just to move forward by 4 steps.

Answer (score 1):

This function inserts 4 spaces at the beginning of each line of the region:

```
(defun my-indent (reg-beg reg-end)
     (interactive "r") ;; r: take the active region and give its boundaries as arguments
     (save-excursion
       (replace-regexp "^" "    " nil reg-beg reg-end)))
```

evil mode's `>` does it too.

Comment: As mentioned in its docstring, `replace-regexp` is for interactive use only. In particular, it sets the mark, which can be annoying.

Comment: thanks. Quoting the doc: `This function is usually the wrong thing to use in a Lisp program.
What you probably want is a loop like this:
  (while (re-search-forward REGEXP nil t)
    (replace-match TO-STRING nil nil))
which will run faster and will not set the mark or print anything.
`

Comment: Wonderful snippet, much useful. Thank you @Ehvince.